# How to configure firebase with angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am beginner of angular 6. I am trying to configure angular 6 with firebase, but at the time of set data i am getting below error.

FirebaseError {code: "app/no-app", message: "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been cre…- call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", ngDebugContext: DebugContext_, ngErrorLogger: ƒ, …}
code: "app/no-app"
message: "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)."
name: "[DEFAULT]"
ngDebugContext: DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 76, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
ngErrorLogger: ƒ ()
stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).↵    at error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73214:21)↵    at app (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73097:13)↵    at Object.serviceNamespace [as firestore] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73155:47)↵    at RegiComponent.push../src/app/regi/regi.component.ts.RegiComponent.saveData (http://localhost:4200/main.js:315:68)↵    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/RegiComponent.ngfactory.js:214:27)↵    at handleEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:55060:41)↵    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56154:25)↵    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:55857:12)↵    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52509:25)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52956:38"
**proto**: Error. 
Please have look of my app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegiComponent } from './regi/regi.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegiComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
   AngularFirestoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my environment.ts

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBNTXxgG5hkzY3_E6E3VRwlMQ798wqBjXA",
    authDomain: "firsapp-f3cf4.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://firsapp-f3cf4.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "firsapp-f3cf4",
    storageBucket: "firsapp-f3cf4.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "736958488941"
  }
  //firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
};
```

Below is my function i am calling on click

```js
saveData($event){
    let name     : string;
    let email    : string;
    let passWord : string;
    let city     : string[]; 
    //var database = firebase.database();
    // Add a new document in collection "cities"
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    // Add a new document in collection "cities"
    db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
      city :  ['A','B', 'C', 'D'],
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
```

Please help me if you need any further info please know me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using angularfire2 service [AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) instead of directly trying to access 'firebase`. You can stream data from the collection using either [valueChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges) or [snapshotChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) and utilize RxJS operators to additional work with the data as needed.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({ /* ... */})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Should ideally use strong types instead of 'any' for better IDE support
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<any>('cities');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // use RxJS operators to use the data as needed
    this.items.subscribe(cities => console.log(cities));
  }

  saveData() {
    this.itemsCollection.doc('LA').set({ city:  ['A','B', 'C', 'D']} );
  }
}
```

I'd highly recommend to review all the angularfire2 Cloud Firestore [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#cloud-firestore) before continuing as well.

Hopefully that helps!